How to pass parameters in the body of an xmlHttpRequest post?
I am trying to log page views to my own server using <amp-analytics>, and would like to include various features of the page (title, language, page type and other custom items) as variables in the body of a POST.
I had expected to use the vars variable, but I don't seem to be able to make this do anything at all. So currently, my code looks like this:
<amp-analytics><script type='application/json'>{
"requests":{
    "eventLog":"https:\/\/btkdock:8890\/json\/access-log\/log-page-view"},
    "triggers":{
        "trackPageView":{
            "on":"visible",
            "request":"eventLog",
            "extraUrlParams":{
                "title":"${title}",
                "whatever":"testing, testing"
            }
         }
      },"transport":{"transport":"beacon","xhrpost":true,"useBody":true}}
</script></amp-analytics>

This is fine, except that the URL parameters don't come out as individual post variables. Rather, the post body appears to be a single JSON-encoded array, with no variable name - the source looks like this when I look at the Payload tab in Chrome:
{"title":"The orchestra is changing: talking sustainability with the Bamberg Symphony | Bachtrack","whatever":"testing, testing"}

The effect of this is that I can't use $_POST to retrieve the variables in PHP, which makes them useless.
If I get rid of the useBody:true option, then I get the payload view that I want (looking like below) but at the price of including all the data in the URL, which I really don't want to do.
title=The%20orchestra%20is%20changing%3A%20talking%20sustainability%20with%20the%20Bamberg%20Symphony%20%7C%20Bachtrack&whatever=testing%2C%20testing

Can anyone explain what is the correct configuration to have the variables in the POST body, but formatted in such a way that they I can use $_POST in PHP to retrieve them?
